# How to make pure components in react js using functional approach i.e. non class based

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, jsx

How to make pure component using in functional react component ?

```
const MyComponent = () => { 
return (<h1>I am functional component.</h1>)
}
export default MyComponent;
```

How to make a pure component out of the above code ?

Comment: What is pure component? What is functional approach? Your example is a stateless function component already.

Answer (score 1):

you can use React.memo

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => { 
return (<h1>I am functional component.</h1>)
}
export default React.memo(MyComponent);
```